# Write each of the columns of a dataframe as the columns of an excel file

Tags: r, excel

I'm working with a file format called `.fef` that has the following structure.

```
patientId 1      NA      NA          NA       NA
Probes             Symbol  FoldChange  green    red
124 427 5849 CA    A2M     -2.13       52 24
```

To write this dataframe I'm using the function:

```
fwrite(dat, file = "C:/Users/patient1.fef"), append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = " ", col.names = FALSE)
```

This creates a file that can be opened with excel where all the values are in the first column, separated by a space.

What I want is each of the columns of the dataframe to be in a column of the excel file.

However the output of the `fwrite` function gives an excel file where all the columns are in the first column of the excel file.

As this is a `.fef` file I can't use functions as `write_excel`.

Comment: You need to convert the fef to xlsx or csv to be compatable with excel. What is the output of `dim(dat)`? For csv, it would be `fwrite(sep = ",")`

Comment: Thanks @danloo The output of 'dim (dat)` is `18052     5`. The problem with writing as xlsx is that, how can I then change to .fef? Just by renaming them?

Comment: You can't. You can not have a file that is both fef and xlsx. You need to use function `write_excel`. Excel can't handle fef

Comment: Then I need to write a file `.fef` in that format @danlooo. Is that possible?

Comment: Seems that you already did it using `fwrite`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to separate the text of the first columns into multiple columns with the command "rngAll$TextToColumns(DataType = 1, Other = TRUE, OtherChar = " ", ConsecutiveDelimiter = TRUE)" (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns for the different options). I have been able to separate the text of the first column with the code below. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(stringr)
library(RDCOMClient)

file.rename(from = "D:\\data_File.fef",
             to = "D:\\data_File2.csv")

text <- readLines("D:\\data_File2.csv")
text <- stringr::str_replace_all(text, pattern = "(\\d{2,5})([:space:]{1,5})(\\d{2,5})", "\\1\\3")
text <- stringr::str_replace_all(text, pattern = "(\\d{2,5})([:space:]{1,5})(\\d{2,5})", "\\1\\3")
text <- stringr::str_replace_all(text, pattern = "(patientId)([:space:]{1,5})(\\d{1,5})", "\\1\\3")

fileConn <- file("D:\\data_File3.csv")
writeLines(text, fileConn)
close(fileConn)

path_Excel_File1 <- "D:\\data_File3.csv"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()

rngAll <- Sheets[[1]]$Range("A1:A5")
rngAll$TextToColumns(DataType = 1, Other = TRUE, OtherChar = " ", ConsecutiveDelimiter = TRUE)
```

You can also use the command fwrite(dat, file = "C:/Users/patient1.fef"), append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, sep = ";", col.names = FALSE) and save your file as a csv file. It is more easy to separate the text with a delimiter that is not a space character such as " ".